# Is right-to-left operator associativity in R possible?

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica, associativity, magrittr

I'm new to R, and I just discovered I suffer from [Bracket Phobia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17315/2266) (see comment in the link). I like the way `magrittr` notation `%>%` works, because it avoids nested parenthesis in some situations, and makes code more readable. I came from `Mathematica`, where there is a very similar native `//` notation to do what `%>%` does. Here are some R and Mathematica comparisons:

```
#R Notation    
c(1.5,-2.3,3.4) %>% round %>% abs %>% sum
```

```
#Mathematica Notation
{1.5,-2.3,3.4}//Round//Abs//Total
```

So far so good, but, my question is:

**Is there some way to mimic [Mathematica @ notation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseShorthandNotations.html), with right-to-left associativity in `R`?**

Here is how it works in Mathematica, to solve the same code above:

```
Total@Abs@Round@{1.5,-2.3,3.4}
```

In Mathematica it can also be write as:

```
Total[Abs[Round[{1.5,-2.3,3.4}]]]
```

just like in `R` it would be:

```
sum(abs(round(c(1.5,-2.3,3.4))))
```

But it would be much more clean (and cool) to have in `R` something like this:

```
sum@abs@round@c(1.5,-2.3,3.4)
```

PS: I know `@` is used in S4 classes, and is not a good idea. This is just an illustrative comparison.

Comment: You should look at the proto package.

Comment: Do do something like this in R you'd need an operator with right-to-left associativity and it doesn't appear to be possible to define such an operator.

Comment: @MrFlick tks for your comment. I changed the post topic to make it clearer.

Comment: This topic is also discussed in `magrittr` issue #26:

https://github.com/smbache/magrittr/issues/26

Comment: About notation creation: [question 32305096](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305096)

Comment: @murta thanks for the links on the github issue.  Please also see the my response to your question.  I think it is a better solution with fewer limitations.  You might want to pick it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **backpipe** package was designed and created for this purpose.  It provides a backpipe (right-to-left) operator for **magrittr**, **pipeR** and generally for any forward pipe operator.  **backpipe** can be found on [github](https://github.com/decisionpatterns/backpipe) and on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/backpipe).

```
library(magrittr)  # or library(pipeR)
library(backpipe)

x <- c(1.5,-2.3,3.4)
sum %<% abs %<% round %<% x

all.equal(                             # TRUE
      x %>% round %>% abs %>% sum,
      sum %<% abs %<% round %<% x
)
```

**backpipe** also is not limited by additional parameters as is the case of the @BenBolker's solution.  This, for example, works with **backpipe** :

```
mean(na.rm=TRUE) %<% c(1:3,NA)
```

See also the discussion on the [magrittr github issue](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr/issues/26) that discuss this.

Answer (score 16):

I haven't tested/thought about this carefully at all, but defining function composition via an operator (as below) seems to work in a couple of test cases:

```
library(magrittr)

## operator defined as  "left-pointing arrow" at the 
##    suggestion of @ClausWilke:
"%<%" <- function(x,y) { if (is(y,"function")) 
          function(z) x(y(z)) 
      else x(y) }

x <- c(1.5,-2.3,3.4)
all.equal(x %>% round %>% abs %>% sum,
          sum %<% abs %<% round %<% x)

x <- rnorm(1000)
all.equal(x %>% round %>% abs %>% sum,
          sum %<% abs %<% round %<% x)
```

The syntax is not as nice as being able to use a single character (such as `@`) for the composition operator, but even if you could find an unused one (all the obvious ones `[!@#$%^&*~|]` are taken, and masking them would be a terrible idea) there's a parser limitation: user-defined binary operators in R must be of the form `%?%`.

Comment: This is very interesting. It's a pity that wrap with `%` is needed, but I believe that is the best that can be done in R by users. I'll wait until the end of the bounty to choose your answer, just to stimulate another ones. +1

Comment: Just for curiosity. Do you know if it's possible to change parser behaviour? Like, to test something like: sum>>abs>>round>>c(1.5,-2.3,3.4) ?

Comment: Not without **extreme** low-level hacking of the R source code ... e.g. you'd have to find the parsing code in the low-level C code and modify it appropriately.

Comment: Any reason not to define the operator as `%<%`, to indicate that the data is sent from right to left?

Comment: @ClausWilke I think it's a nice suggestion.

Comment: @BenBolker I like the simplicity, but it doesn't quite work.  Consider: ` mean(na.rm=TRUE) %<% c(1:3,NA)`.  The additional argument to `mean` breaks your solution.

Answer (score 8):

How about using `compose` from hadley's `purrr` package?

```
compose(sum,abs,round,c)(1.5,-2.3,3.4)
```