# Is it possible to beautifully display the pipeline character (%>%) in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

The pipeline operator `%>%` is used a lot in `dplyr`. I came across this settings to beautifully write it as an unicode triple arrow character like this:

[image]

I'm wondering is it possible to get the same display in `RStudio`?

p.s. The source for Emacs including elisp code are here:

https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/96

Comment: You can always search and ask here: https://support.rstudio.com

Comment: This would be very interesting. I came from Mathematica, where such notations are very common, and miss something like that in RStudio. +1

Comment: @Pascal Thanks. I've posted a question on RStudio site: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/205430237-Is-it-possible-to-beautifully-display-the-pipeline-character-in-RStudio-

Comment: I have been thinking about this as well.  My thoughts were for a "fat dot" rather that the triple arrow.