# Is right-to-left operator associativity in R possible? (other version)

Tags: r, associativity

In R left-to-right associativity is the norm, for instance:

```
5 - 3 - 1 == (5 - 3) - 1 # TRUE
5 - 3 - 1 == 5 - (3 - 1) # FALSE
```

Is there a way to get right-to-left associativity instead, for a given operator?

Note that I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31305342/3902976); however it does not answer my question above, here is why:

```
library(backpipe)
"%diff%" <- function(x, y) y - x
"%-%" <- backpipe("%diff%")
5 %-% 3 %-% 1 == (5 %-% 3) %-% 1 # TRUE
5 %-% 3 %-% 1 == 5 %-% (3 %-% 1) # FALSE
```

Comment: why do you want this

Comment: I have an operator `%->%`, which is actually mathematically associative; but the structure of the objects it acts upon makes it much more efficient to evaluate `a %->% (b %->% c)` rather than `(a %->% b) %->% c`. And I want to avoid too many parentheses...